# string indices must be integers URL

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get name and date of all the holidays but got this error "string indices must be integers"

```
import requests
import datetime
from datetime import date 
url = 'https://api.alpha.ca.gov/StateHolidayCalendar/all'

resp = requests.get(url)
text = resp.text      

print(text)
print('As of',date.today(), ', the remaining holidays in the US for this year are: ')
for h in text:
    print ('holiday: ',h['name'], ' is on ',h['date'])
```

`https://api.alpha.ca.gov/StateHolidayCalendar/all` returns the following response:

```
[
  {
    "name": "New Year's Day",
    "date": "2020-01-01T08:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "name": "Martin Luther King Jr. Day",
    "date": "2020-01-20T08:00:00.000Z"
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: @DeepSpace, I want to get value of "name" in "name": "Christmas Day" and date in "date": "2021-12-25T08:00:00.000Z" . i.e.: Christmas Day and 2021-12-25

Comment: Next time please include the content of the response in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`text` is a string, hence `h` is a string, `h['name']` and `h['date']` make no sense at all.

You should parse the response using `.json()`:

```
...
data = resp.json()
```

Then you can treat it as a list of dictionaries:

```
for holiday in data:  
    print(holiday['name'], holiday['date'])
```

will output

```
New Year's Day 2020-01-01T08:00:00.000Z
Martin Luther King Jr. Day 2020-01-20T08:00:00.000Z
Presidents' Day 2020-02-17T08:00:00.000Z
Cesar Chavez Day 2020-03-31T08:00:00.000Z
Memorial Day 2020-05-25T08:00:00.000Z
Independence Day 2020-07-04T08:00:00.000Z
Labor Day 2020-09-07T08:00:00.000Z
Veterans Day 2020-11-11T08:00:00.000Z
Thanksgiving Day 2020-11-26T08:00:00.000Z
Day after Thanksgiving 2020-11-27T08:00:00.000Z
Christmas Day 2020-12-25T08:00:00.000Z
New Year's Day 2021-01-01T08:00:00.000Z
Martin Luther King Jr. Day 2021-01-18T08:00:00.000Z
Presidents' Day 2021-02-15T08:00:00.000Z
Cesar Chavez Day 2021-03-31T08:00:00.000Z
Memorial Day 2021-05-31T08:00:00.000Z
Independence Day 2021-07-04T08:00:00.000Z
Labor Day 2021-09-06T08:00:00.000Z
Veterans Day 2021-11-11T08:00:00.000Z
Thanksgiving Day 2021-11-25T08:00:00.000Z
Day after Thanksgiving 2021-11-26T08:00:00.000Z
Christmas Day 2021-12-25T08:00:00.000Z
```